# rsync: is possible to copy only the used space of qcow2 or raw image?

Tags: rsync, sparse-files

Simple question.
I have a 200G qcow2 or raw disk image, but of 200G only 30G are used.
If I do

```
rsync -avP
```

copy all the 200G on usb disk or network and it wast time,space and network bandwidth.
Is possible to copy only the 30G?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if the file is sparse, `rsync` can copy it without filling in the holes with zeroes.

To do this, use `rsync` with its `--sparse` (or `-S`) option.